# Button as subview, click start superview

Tags: ios

I have a button that will be a subview added to a another UIView, like Path does.  The idea is that this button will remain static in one corner of the screen while the user can scroll through the UIVIew behind it.
I am handling the pointsinside method, to know when a user clicks whether it was on the button or the super view.

```
 - (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
 {
     return CGRectContainsPoint(customButton.frame, point);
 }
```

My question is, if the user does click in the button, I need to open up a UIImagePickerController, which is a property of the superview. how can I do that on the superview though?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you should add an event to button by addTarget method.

Answer (score 0):

If the button is **Guaranteed** (and I mean that, because it will crash without a guarantee) to be the subview of the superview you mention, then casting `self.superview` will allow you access to it's `UIImagePickerController` property.  A much safer implementation would use a weak reference to the owning superview, then property manipulation would fail gracefully if you tried to re-use the button without it's superview.

Comment: is there an assumption that the superview has to be a viewcontroller? or is there a way to have this happen where the superview is another UIView?

Comment: @Kalamantina No, the assumption you're making with casting is that 1) the view even ***has*** a superview, 2) that the superview is the class that has the correctly named property.